How to fix '@ProjectPermissionDenied The Developer Console project is not permitted to make this request.'
errors: [
  {
    message: '@ProjectPermissionDenied The Developer Console project is not permitted to make this request.',
    domain: 'global',
    reason: 'forbidden'
  }
],

When I try to create add-on attachments using the API for an assignment that was manually created in Classroom, I encounter this error. However, if the assignment was created through the API, I can add attachments without any issues. What could be wrong? Other add-ons, like Nearpod, are able to create add-on attachments for assignments that were manually created.

Welcome to Stackoverflow! This article states that this error Indicate that your application cannot make the desired request. It can only be made by the Developer Console project of the OAuth client ID that created the resource. You can check this link and see if this makes sense
ProjectPermissionDenied

Can you also provide the scopes that the account that you are using have? Maybe you are using a service account? What scope this account have?

There are two ways to create an add-on attachment (1) if the teacher creates the assignment manually in the Classroom UI, only the teacher can attach your add-on  through the iframe flow. (2) Alternatively, you can create an assignment via the API & directly attach your add-on through the API. You cannot directly attach your add-on via API to an assignment the teacher created in the UI; you don't have write permission to that resource.

How to fixed Project Permission Denied problem for update draft grade and assigned grade of student submission from Google Classroom
This seems to be related to your case
